# How can I boost 1 Volts 30 Ampere input to 5V with maximum Current limit of 5A?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, power-electronics, converter

How can I boost 1 Volt 30 Ampere DC input to 5V DC with a maximum Current limit of 5A?

Comment: AC or DC supplies?

Comment: DC supply from a fuel cell

Comment: A boost converter.

Comment: You need to design a boost converter. It won't be easy with 1 V input.

Comment: Is it possible to design such a boost converter?

Comment: Sure thing! You probably need an auxiliary boost converter to create a say 5 or 12 V rail in order to drive the main boost converter since there are probable few to none MOSFETs available which can do 30 A at 1 V Vgs.

Comment: [Have you checked to see what the usual suspects have to offer?](http://www.ti.com/tool/pmp9772)

Comment: It might not be possible to get 5A out. 30 W in, 25 W out requires ~83% efficiency. With just 1 V input, there would be considerable loss due to high current in conductors and components. Can you place two or more cells in series?

Comment: @santoshkumars are we done here? Is your question answered now?

Comment: @Andyaka, Yes the question is answered and is satisfactory.

Comment: @Andyaka, done upvoting the answer  thanks for informing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to design two boost converters because you won't get that direct power transfer from one common booster. Firstly, design a low power boost converter that can produce a supply of maybe 5 to 10 volts at a maximum load current of 100 mA. This will be used to provide MOSFET gate switching signals for the high power booster circuit.

Here's a low power booster that looks like it nearly fits the bill: -

[image]

If you can find MOSFETs that have a low gate voltage drive capability (around 1 volts VGS(th) you might be getting close to a solution. Of course, once you are generating your 5 volt output you can steal some energy from it to give the MOSFETs a bigger gate drive.

Comment: Hey! You stole my idea!

Comment: @winny great minds think alike I'd like to believe LOL.

Comment: Ya both swiped it from TI.

Comment: I'm a linear tech guy first then if they can't offer I'll think about TI.